# tomcat strange issue with multiple study

Tags: linux, tomcat, alias

We are using `tomcat version 7` (with front end `Apache`) and we have following configuration at setenv.sh file

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.proxy.name="www.example.com"
```

Currently i have add one more domain name `www.foo.com` and point to same tomcat (Multiple domain name for same tomcat)

but when i type `www.foo.com` it will automatic convert in www.example.com in browser search bar.

But if i change following setting in `setevn.sh` file it works for foo but not for example

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.proxy.name="www.foo.com"
```

Question:

is there a way i can use multiple domain name to point on same tomcat like `Alias` ? what is `-Dserver.proxy.name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache in front specify virtualhosts with proxies to your tomcats. Don't even bother trying to accomplish this down in your application srever. Ideally you'd use something like the mod_jk Apache module for load balancing.

Comment: We are using `mod_proxy` to pass traffic to tomcat server. In my case we are not using load balacing method it is `1-0-1`